# Split a big txt file to do grep - unix

Tags: bash, unix, split, grep

I work (unix, shell scripts) with txt files that are millions field separate by pipe and not separated by `\n` or `\r`.
something like this:

```
field1a|field2a|field3a|field4a|field5a|field6a|[...]|field1d|field2d|field3d|field4d|field5d|field6d|[...]|field1m|field2m|field3m|field4m|field5m|field6m|[...]|field1z|field2z|field3z|field4z|field5z|field6z|
```

All text is in the same line.

The number of fields is fixed for every file.

(in this example I have `field1=name; field2=surname; field3=mobile phone; field4=email; field5=office phone; field6=skype`)

When I need to find a field (ex `field2`), command like grep doesn't work (in the same line).

I think that a good solution can be do a script that split every 6 field with a "\n" and after do a grep. I'm right? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just wondering, why are your text files built like that?

Comment: why would anybody downvote this question? because the OP has to process a file in a stupid format??

Comment: I receive this files. Is like a file archiver, that save every information processed :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `sed` to split the line in multiple lines:

```
 sed 's/\(\([^|]*|\)\{6\}\)/\1\n/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

explanation:

- we have to use heavy backslash-escaping of `(){}` which makes the code slightly unreadable.
- but in short:

  - the term `(([^|]*|){6})` (backslashes removed for readability) between `s/` and `/\1`, will match:

    - `[^|]*` any character but '|', repeated multiple times
    - `|` followed by a '|'
    - the above is obviously one column and it is grouped together with enclosing parantheses `(` and `)`
    - the entire group is repeated 6 times `{6}`
    - and this is again grouped together with enclosing parantheses `(` and `)`, to form one full set

the rest of the term is easy to read:

- replace the above (the entire dataset of 6 fields) with `\1\n`, the part between `/` and `/g`
- `\1` refers to the "first" group in the sed-expression (the "first" group that is started, so it's the entire dataset of 6 fields)
- `\n` is the newline character
- so replace the entire dataset of 6 fields by itself followed by a newline
- and do so repeatedly (the trailing `g`)

Answer (score 3):

With awk :

```
$ cat a
field1a|field2a|field3a|field4a|field5a|field6a|field1d|field2d|field3d|field4d|field5d|field6d|field1m|field2m|field3m|field4m|field5m|field6m|field1z|field2z|field3z|field4z|field5z|field6z|



$ awk -F"|" '{for (i=1;i<NF;i=i+6) {for (j=0; j<6; j++) printf $(i+j)"|"; printf "\n"}}' a

field1a|field2a|field3a|field4a|field5a|field6a|
field1d|field2d|field3d|field4d|field5d|field6d|
field1m|field2m|field3m|field4m|field5m|field6m|
field1z|field2z|field3z|field4z|field5z|field6z|
```

Here you can easily set the length of line.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

you can use `sed` to convert every 6th `|` to a newline.

In my version of tcsh I can do:

```
sed 's/\(\([^|]\+|\)\{6\}\)/\1\n/g' filename
```

consider this:

```
> cat bla
a1|b2|c3|d4|

> sed 's/\(\([^|]\+|\)\{6\}\)/\1\n/g' bla
a1|b2|
c3|d4|
```

This is how the regex works:

- `[^|]` is any non-`|` character.
- `[^|]\+` is a sequence of at least one non-`|` characters.
- `[^|]\+|` is a sequence of at least one non-`|` characters followed by a `|`.
- `\([^|]\+|\)` is a sequence of at least one non-`|` characters followed by a `|`, grouped together
- `\([^|]\+|\)\{6\}` is 6 consecutive such groups.
- `\(\([^|]\+|\)\{6\}\)` is 6 consecutive such groups, grouped together.

The replacement just takes this sequence of 6 groups and adds a newline to the end.

Comment: `sed` is usually a standalone binary, and thus does not depend on the shell you are using.

Comment: @umläute: you're right, but there might be different requirements for escaping the parentheses and the `|`, so I thought it best to mention this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it with `awk`

```
awk -v RS="|" '{printf $0 (NR%7?RS:"\n")}' file
field1a|field2a|field3a|field4a|field5a|field6a|[...]
field1d|field2d|field3d|field4d|field5d|field6d|[...]
field1m|field2m|field3m|field4m|field5m|field6m|[...]
field1z|field2z|field3z|field4z|field5z|field6z|
```

Just adjust the `NR%7` to number of field you to what suites you.

Comment: +1 though better to modify the `ORS`. `awk -v RS="|" '{ORS=(NR%7?"|":"\n")}1' file`

Comment: Thanks. Changed `"|"` to `RS`

Comment: Uhms, good one! I knew some NR/RS trick could be done for this question :)

Answer (score 1):

What about printing the lines on blocks of six?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=6) {print $(i), $(i+1), $(i+2), $(i+3), $(i+4), $(i+5)}}' file
field1a|field2a|field3a|field4a|field5a|field6a
field1d|field2d|field3d|field4d|field5d|field6d
field1m|field2m|field3m|field4m|field5m|field6m
field1z|field2z|field3z|field4z|field5z|field6z
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` set input and output field separator as `|`.
- `{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=6) {print $(i), $(i+1), $(i+2), $(i+3), $(i+4), $(i+5)}}` loop through items on blocks of 6. Every single time, print six of them. As `print` end up writing a new line, then you are done.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat the files as being in multiple lines, then make `\n` the field separator.  For example, to get the 2nd column, just do:

```
tr \| \\n < input-file | sed -n 2p
```

To see which columns match a regex, do:

```
tr \| \\n < input-file | grep -n regex
```